# How to align horizontally these elements?

Tags: alignment, text-alignment, text-align

I would like to align horizontally these 3 elements which are displayed vertically in my screen.

Could you please let me know how I could fix it ?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="c-section__content&nbsp; c-section__content--flex">
<div class="c-download__text" style="border-left: none;">
<div style="margin: 0 auto;"><a class="c-download" href="" style="width: auto;"><span class="c-download__icon"><span aria-label="download" class="c-icon c-icon-download ">&nbsp;</span></span> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="c-section__content&nbsp; c-section__content--flex">
<div class="c-download__text" style="border-left: none;">
<div style="margin: 0 auto;"><a class="c-download" href="" style="width: auto;"><span class="c-download__icon"><span aria-label="download" class="c-icon c-icon-download ">&nbsp;</span></span> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="c-section__content&nbsp; c-section__content--flex">
<div class="c-download__text" style="border-left: none;">
<div style="margin: 0 auto;"><a class="c-download" href="" style="width: auto;"><span class="c-download__icon"><span aria-label="download" class="c-icon c-icon-download ">&nbsp;</span></span> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Yoni, try moving your code to a code snipet ( ctrl+m )